# sites for having fun with php

Tags: php, puzzle

are there any sites where we have to solve puzzles using php scripts? Similar to [PythonChallenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com)?

**I am aware of most of the programming challenge sites, idea is to find a site which helps to discover the strength and speciality of PHP Scripting the way PythonChallenge does by it's wiki's for each level.**

Comment: You can always try and solve as many Python challenge puzzles as you can with PHP.  Most of the solutions have PHP analogs.

Comment: Thanks for the site, nice one, but edit the link: is http://www.pythonchallenge.com and not http://www.thepythonchallenge.com ;)

Answer (score 2):

http://projecteuler.net/ has programming and math challenges that can be attempted in any language.

Comment: it is highly related to mathematics, i want to see some thing more general like the way it is in pythonchallenge.

Answer (score 1):

http://projecteuler.net/

mostly math challenges, most can be done with php.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [code golf](http://codegolf.com/). It's about solving the tasks with the smallest program.